# Visual Studio 2012 Tests Windows Phone App suddenly fail due to missing reference

Tags: unit-testing, serialization, visual-studio-2012, assemblies

I am developing an app for Windows Phone, and also have a Test project for creating and running tests. This was working fine, but suddenly I am getting an error that the reference System.Runtime.Serialization cannot be found.

Specifically the error is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies.

First of all, shouldn't it be 4.0 not 2.0.5?

I attempted to add a reference to the 4.0 version of System.Runtime.Serialization, but now the error is this:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

I looked all over the projects to find where this reference (2.0.5) is defined so I can update it (not sure how it ever got changed) but have had no luck.

I am using JSON.NET if that matters (5.0.6)

If it is supposed to be 2.0.5 is there any way the project could have been accidentally or automatically changed to be 4.0?

this was working before, so SOMETHING changed, and it certainly wasn't deliberately done by me...

**EDIT**
After looking at the error above, I took another look at my code, and it appears the culprit is this attribute I put on one of my properties:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="NameType")]
```

because the property name differs from the name in the JSON. It runs perfectly, but fails during tests. If I comment it out, the test passes (but the application fails to get this property).

**EDIT2:**
So it appears to me the problem is that Windows Phone has a Windows Phone JSON.NET version, while the test project loads the standard .net40, but the windows phone assembly being tested wants the phone version so it's getting all mucked up...

or something. I feel like I just screwed up the references somehow, but I cannot figure out what.

I tried setting "Copy Local" to true/false, and adding the JSON.NET reference for windows phone to the test project, but then it tells me it's the wrong version...

How do I tell the test project (which is not a windows phone project) to use the windows phone assemblies for test? Do I have to make a new test project that is a windows phone type or something?

Everything was working perfectly until I added an attribute that uses the System.Runtime.Serialization library...

Comment: Ensure you've got the correct assembly of JSON.NET referenced in your project. I believe it should be runtime v4.0.30319 (the JSON assembly) for v5.0.6. Did you use Nuget or manually install it?

Comment: I did install using nuget, both on the WP8 project and the Test project, it does appear that the winphone project is using a different version, so I added manually the reference to match the WP8 version, but now i'm still getting the latter error (assembly manifest definition does not match)...

Comment: Might be worth installing from Nuget to ensure that the issue isn't related to the assembly version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight File Not Found System.Runtime.Serialization on Deserialization from Newtonsoft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238187/silverlight-file-not-found-system-runtime-serialization-on-deserialization-from)

Comment: thanks for your input, I updated the description with new findings, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out being a problem with my code, which is weird because obviously that's not the error message I got...

anyway, the problem appears to be that the JSON property was "NameType" and I was using "Type" with a JsonProperty(Name="NameType") and I guess the compiler didn't like that.

Changing the property name to match appears to have fixed the issue.

many thanks to all for your input!

Comment: this also apparently happens when you reference properties, methods, events, etc that are not consistent between frameworks; vs just freaks out and gives up... I haven't found a good way to workaround this